# Trouble understanding the definition of $O(\epsilon_{machine})$

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics, numerical-linear-algebra

> I am having trouble understanding the definition of $O(\epsilon_{machine})$.
>    The text i'm using defines it as:

[image]

> Now, i'm asked to show that $(1+O(\epsilon_{machine}))(1+O(\epsilon_{machine}))=1+O(\epsilon_{machine})$. For simplicity, i'll denote $\epsilon = \epsilon_{machine}$ (hopefully this does not change anything for now).

[image]

> My confusion is, if I suppose that $f(\epsilon)=(1+O(\epsilon))(1+O(\epsilon)).$ Are the two $O(\epsilon)'s$ on the RHS of the equation the same? That is, would it be correct to say that I have two functions $\varphi_1(t), \varphi_2(t)$ such that $|\varphi_1(t)|<C_1\psi_1(t)$ and $|\varphi_2(t)| <C_2\psi_2(t)$ (where $\psi_1(t) = \psi_2(t) = \epsilon$)?

Comment: The $O$ functions themselves don't have to be the same, but the $\psi$'s that you use for the upper bounds can be chosen to both be just $\epsilon$. For example, you might have $(1+\epsilon)(1+2\epsilon)$.